# Disabling mat-expansion without changing text opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have created an angular mat-expansion-panel which will perform alert-box event and expand the panel too. My requirement is to show only alert-box but not expansion.

I tried disabling the mat expansion but it will change the text opacity value which i dont want.
I even tried css point-events but it will make event alert box not to function. Please help me with this.

HTML CODE:

```
 <mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title (click)="onClick()" >
       Hi
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Hello
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
<p>hi there</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

TS code:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  onClick(){
    alert("something");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that `event.stopPropagation();` is able to prevent a background-process from executing. Add it to your method like that:

```
export class AppComponent { 
      onClick(){
        alert("something");
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
```

Comment: Dude it was an coincidence. I actually figured it out and opened my question to delete but u gave the correct answer. Thanks you man

Comment: Awesome! Can you tell me what your solution was though? Out of curiosity.

Comment: same dude. event.stopPropagation() is what i have used for not expanding row (basically its stops parent event, so it wont expand)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

Step 1 - remove this code.

```
<mat-panel-description>
    Hello
</mat-panel-description>
```

Step 2 - For this particular container change this css.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0 24px 16px;
}
```

to

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Whenever we are expanding accordion it's height is changing, you can keep it same using these two `Input` bindings.

```
@Input()
collapsedHeight: string

@Input()
expandedHeight: string
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Even after using those @inputs panel is expanding in the collapsed height area. But i dont want that to open.

Comment: try to set `display: none` for `.mat-expansion-panel-body`